# React - JavaScript: How to properly position a dropdown menu on top of a Google Map

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I have been trying to position a `dropdown` menu ona specific position of my google-map, to be specific on top right (or top left is ok too). 
Below is what I am **currently** getting:

[image: error]

Below is the **expected** result:

[image: correct]

**EDITS**

After tryin `margin-top: 100px;` the combobx will move down, but if I type `margin-bottom: 500px;` the dropdown remains in the center (where the origin is).
The same is if I type `margin-left: 500px` the dropdown will move on the right, but if I type `margin-right: 500px` the dropdown will not move further than the origin.
It seems that the only allowable movements are down and left but not up and right.
Below a screensots:

[image: anchor]

The code I am using is the following:

**GoogleMap.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, /*CardSubtitle,*/ Button } from 'reactstrap';
import ShipTracker from '../components/ShipTracker';

const MapContainer = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 200px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-areas: "google-map   sidebar" "ship-tracker sidebar";

    .google-map {
        background: #424242;
        grid-area: google-map;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .map-sidebar {
        background: #9dc183;
        grid-area: sidebar;
    }
    .ship-tracker {
        grid-area: ship-tracker;
    }
`;

var expanded = false;
function showCheckboxes() {
// show checkboxes
}

const BoatMap = () => (
    <div className="google-map">
        <GoogleMapReact
            bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'My_KEY' }}
            center={{
                lat: 42.4,
                lng: -71.1
            }}
            zoom={11}
        >
            {/* Insert components here */}
            <form>
                <div class="multiselect">
                    <div class="combo-companies" onClick={showCheckboxes}>
                        <select>
                            <option>Select an option</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="overSelect" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="checkboxes">
                        <label for="one">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="CD" />Marker-1
                        </label>
                        <label for="two">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="DJ" />Marker-2
                        </label>
                        <label for="three">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="DT" />Marker-3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </GoogleMapReact>
    </div>
);
```

**GoogleMap.css**

```
.combo-companies {
    position: absolute;
    height: 34px;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-radius: 3px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.multiselect {
    width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
    position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
    display: none;
    border: 1px #dadada solid;
}
```

**What I gave done so far:**

1) I used [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to determine where the google-map should have been. After that and going again throughout the documentation, I made sure about the location of the grid. So [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) it should be good.

2) I think the main problem could be determined from the use of `relative` and `absolute` parameters on the components as I read a on some posts like [this one](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react) and [this](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/API.md).
Althought useful, I could not figure out the problem.

3) I know I am close to the solution because the only thing left if just the rendering and came across [this useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440178/react-native-dropdown-position) and thought that could have been my solution, but it wasn't.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in GoogleMap.css

```
.multiselect{
width: 200px;
position: absolute; /*Also try relative if this doesn't work */
margin: 2vh 50vw auto auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reading the question. Good progress :), it is not now in the middle but moved horizontally on the right. now, how do I move it up to arrive to the position I am looking for? Position is in fact `position: relative`

Comment: You will have to adjust the margin values according to your needs. Or try dropping a complete page screenshot so people might be able to help you better.

Comment: I update the question with **EDITS**. Basically the dropdown seems to move only down and right and not top and left. I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: Well, that's the way it works. Margin-bottom won't push your element above, it will push the next element below. Try setting lesser margin-top and greater margin-left, that will move the dropdown in the top left corner. You can also try negative margin-top to further push it upwards.